# How to create a dynamic chart in google site with data from google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I come from Vietnam so my English not quite! Please people sympathize if I have written anything confusing!
I want to create a line chart in google site with data taken from google spreadsheet. If the data in the spreadsheet update then chart in the site automatically changes (like chart that when we insert in the spreadsheet).
The spreadsheet is response from the form : http://goo.gl/forms/jRjl0DCAf3

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Taken verbatim from [here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1680639?hl=en) in Google Sites help. I have italicized the most important information for automatically updating the chart.

> To insert a chart into a site, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the site page you'd like to insert a chart into.
> 2. Click the edit page button.
> 3. Go to the **Insert** menu, and select **Chart**.
> 4. Select a spreadsheet from the list that contains the chart data you'd like to display.
>
>     - If the spreadsheet already contains a chart, you can select the chart. This will be a snapshot of the spreadsheet chart, and the chart won't update if spreadsheet data is modified. To insert a chart that dynamically updates, open the charts editor and select the **Live** option.
>
>     - If the spreadsheet doesn't already have a chart in it, enter a range of data. *If you mark **Live**, the chart will update as spreadsheet data is modified. If you mark **Snapshot**, the chart won't update unless you manually do so.*  Learn more about [creating a chart](/docs/topic/1361474).
> 5. Once you've selected or created a chart, click **OK**.
> 6. On the next page, you can adjust the dimensions of the chart and change the title. When you've done so, click **Save**, and the chart will be inserted into the page.
>
> *Keep in mind:*
> *Anyone viewing your site can view a Snapshot chart. If you've selected Live updating for your chart, only people who have access to the spreadsheet will be able to view an updated version of the original chart.*

Comment: For more complex and interactive charts look at apps script dashboards. Trival to add if you have some coding skills.